# Unity normal maps look wrong (URP, iOS)

Tags: unity, ios, materials, normal-mapping, vuforia

We're building an AR-enabled app with Vuforia and Unity 2019.3, using the Universal Render Pipeline. 
Trouble is, on iOS our models that have normal maps in their materials look totally bad, as you can see. [image: Image of bad graphics]
This is how it's supposed to look: (ignore the differences in the orange background item)

[image: supposed to look like this]

If we remove the normal maps, the models look fine, but since the normal maps add a lot of detail and depth to the scene, we'd rather not ditch them. 
We've tried to change the import settings of the normal maps, changing the compression formats and such, but that didn't make a difference.

Here's an image of the material settings:
[image]

Is there another solution to fix this?

On Android, there's no problem, by the way.